# compare two string in java result in percentage

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

I have to compare two strings which 4000-5000 characters.

I need result in percentage(i.e. 70% - 80% matched), in java.

Kindly suggest me any solution for it.

Regards

Comment: I kindly suggest you start coding a solution and come back when you have an actual problem.

Comment: analyse, implement, run.

Comment: Hi Mena, 

I am new to java, kindly give me some hint about it.

Comment: @zidan007: that is still no reason to ask us to do your homework for you, without even trying yourself first.

Comment: @zidan007 Then now is the time to start learning it. Step 1: start with the basics and not with these kind of problems.

Comment: I came across same question. [This Q&A](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/147809/Compare-Strings-for-Percentage-Match) gave me an hint to use Levenshtein Distance.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the code to compare two strings and getting result in integer form from 0 to 100.

```
/**
 *
 * @author WARLOCK
 */
public class LockMatch {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        //---Provide source and target strings to lock_match function to compare--//
        System.out.println("Your Strings are Matched="+lock_match("The warlock","The warlock powered by WTPL")+"%");  
    }

    public static int lock_match(String s, String t) {



        int totalw = word_count(s);
        int total = 100;
        int perw = total / totalw;
        int gotperw = 0;

        if (!s.equals(t)) {

            for (int i = 1; i <= totalw; i++) {
                if (simple_match(split_string(s, i), t) == 1) {
                    gotperw = ((perw * (total - 10)) / total) + gotperw;
                } else if (front_full_match(split_string(s, i), t) == 1) {
                    gotperw = ((perw * (total - 20)) / total) + gotperw;
                } else if (anywhere_match(split_string(s, i), t) == 1) {
                    gotperw = ((perw * (total - 30)) / total) + gotperw;
                } else {
                    gotperw = ((perw * smart_match(split_string(s, i), t)) / total) + gotperw;
                }
            }
        } else {
            gotperw = 100;
        }
        return gotperw;
    }

    public static int anywhere_match(String s, String t) {
        int x = 0;
        if (t.contains(s)) {
            x = 1;
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static int front_full_match(String s, String t) {
        int x = 0;
        String tempt;
        int len = s.length();

        //----------Work Body----------//
        for (int i = 1; i <= word_count(t); i++) {
            tempt = split_string(t, i);
            if (tempt.length() >= s.length()) {
                tempt = tempt.substring(0, len);
                if (s.contains(tempt)) {
                    x = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //---------END---------------//
        if (len == 0) {
            x = 0;
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static int simple_match(String s, String t) {
        int x = 0;
        String tempt;
        int len = s.length();


        //----------Work Body----------//
        for (int i = 1; i <= word_count(t); i++) {
            tempt = split_string(t, i);
            if (tempt.length() == s.length()) {
                if (s.contains(tempt)) {
                    x = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //---------END---------------//
        if (len == 0) {
            x = 0;
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static int smart_match(String ts, String tt) {

        char[] s = new char[ts.length()];
        s = ts.toCharArray();
        char[] t = new char[tt.length()];
        t = tt.toCharArray();


        int slen = s.length;
        //number of 3 combinations per word//
        int combs = (slen - 3) + 1;
        //percentage per combination of 3 characters//
        int ppc = 0;
        if (slen >= 3) {
            ppc = 100 / combs;
        }
        //initialising an integer to store the total % this class genrate//
        int x = 0;
        //declaring a temporary new source char array
        char[] ns = new char[3];
        //check if source char array has more then 3 characters//
        if (slen < 3) {
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < combs; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    ns[j] = s[j + i];
                }
                if (cross_full_match(ns, t) == 1) {
                    x = x + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        x = ppc * x;
        return x;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param s
     * @param t
     * @return
     */
    public static int  cross_full_match(char[] s, char[] t) {
        int z = t.length - s.length;
        int x = 0;
        if (s.length > t.length) {
            return x;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i <= z; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j <= (s.length - 1); j++) {
                    if (s[j] == t[j + i]) {
                        // x=1 if any charecer matches
                        x = 1;
                    } else {
                        // if x=0 mean an character do not matches and loop break out
                        x = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (x == 1) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static String split_string(String s, int n) {

        int index;
        String temp;
        temp = s;
        String temp2 = null;

        int temp3 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int strlen = temp.length();
            index = temp.indexOf(" ");
            if (index < 0) {
                index = strlen;
            }
            temp2 = temp.substring(temp3, index);
            temp = temp.substring(index, strlen);
            temp = temp.trim();

        }
        return temp2;
    }

    public static int word_count(String s) {
        int x = 1;
        int c;
        s = s.trim();
        if (s.isEmpty()) {
            x = 0;
        } else {
            if (s.contains(" ")) {
                for (;;) {
                    x++;
                    c = s.indexOf(" ");
                    s = s.substring(c);
                    s = s.trim();
                    if (s.contains(" ")) {
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

Just supply the two strings as argument to lock_match(string1, string2) and it will return the integer value of matching. If the size of string is bigger then increase the total name variable size
in the code.
Like int total=1000
Then the result will be given out of 0 to 1000.
This code is case sensitive.
Uppercase or lowercase both strings to get rid from this problem. 
Source code available at: [lock match](http://www.sourceforge.com/projects/lockmatch)

Comment: I am using your provided code snippet and its useful, thanks for posting

Answer (score 8):

You can use Apache Commons Lang 3.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>${commons.lang.version}</version>
</dependency>

@Test
public void test_stringDistance() throws Exception {
    String teamName = "Partizn Belgrade";
    String propositionName = "Partizan Belgrade";

    // This one seems better
    double distance = StringUtils.getJaroWinklerDistance(teamName, propositionName);
    System.out.println(distance);
}
```

This is print out percentage, the larger the better (100% is exact )

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

**org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.getJaroWinklerDistance(first, second)** is deprecated as of commons-lang3:3.6

Use **new org.apache.commons.text.similarity.JaroWinklerDistance().apply(left, right)** instead where left and right stand for first and second respectively. See maven dependency below

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```